# Using APL symbols in Ubuntu, console only

Tags: keymapping, apl

I have been trying unsuccessfully to setup the keymap on a console to program in APL. My machine is remote, hence I do not have Xorg installed.

How can I setup my keymap/charset to correctly produce APL symbols?

Comment: [Here](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Typing_glyphs_on_Linux) are some instructions to try out. Also feel free to visit the [APL chatroom](https://apl.chat).